# best way to write data to firebase firestore using unreal engine blueprints?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

using unreal engine 4, what's the best solution to writing data to cloud db? my guess (with blueprints that work), in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

i was looking for low cost at startup and simple. i went with firebase's firestore. did anyone try aws dynamoDB or another db?

i used VaRest plugin, which is free and is working great (much better than the two firebase plugins i purchased and no longer use).

shout out to MindDrive TV at youtube. he kindly offers his entire project for download at his youtube page (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0kaN0THVsA&t=632s). i watched his video several times, but did not realize what i missed until downloading his project and insert his make json nodes (which is when my error became apparent).

below are my blueprints, both tested well. ways to improve them or do it differently?

[image: blueprints to write data to firestore]

[image: more blueprints]